# Yii primary key increase by 2

Tags: php, insert, yii, primary-key

Noticed strange thing. In my DB all tables have only **odd primary keys**.

```
 id  |  value
  1  |  10
  3  |  15
  5  |  NULL
  7  |  1
```

In other Yii sites everything ok.

Rows added by different methods and into different tables:

```
$model = new Tbl1;
$model->value = 10;
$model->save();
```

and

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `tbl2` SET `value` = 10';
$command->setText($sql);
$command->execute();
```

This is strange, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your database server(probably, MySQL) check for the `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` variables.

Set these to **`1`**.

---

Information regarding further commands and actions are listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html).

Comment: Thanks, you are right `auto_increment_increment - 2, 
auto_increment_offset - 1`.